# Create a derived function with a parameter

Tags: svelte

it's the first time I'm using Svelte and I'm trying to structure a store.
I read the documentation [here](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store) but there is something that it's not clear to me. Sorry if it it a stupid question.

Basically I created a *readable* store (readable because it doesn't change) and a derived value.
Now I need to create a derived function that takes a parameter.

[Here my code](https://svelte.dev/repl/88223cd22f4c41929bf1587e5e0728b1?version=3.48.0)

`stores.js`:

```js
import { derived, readable, writable } from 'svelte/store'

export const dataset = readable([1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2]);

export const sortedDataset = derived(dataset, ($dataset) => {
  return $dataset.sort();
})

export function getCounterValue(value) { // <- how to implement something like this?
    return dataset.filter((d) => d === value).length;
}
```

`App.svelte`

```js
<script>
    import {dataset, sortedDataset, getCounterValue} from './stores.js'

    console.log('dataset:', $dataset);
    console.log('sorted dataset:', $sortedDataset);
    console.log('2 counter:', getCounterValue(2)); // <- how can I call the function?
</script>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `sort()` mutates the original array, so if you want to prevent that do something like `[...$dataset].sort()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create store derived functions, you just have to return a function from the store (the store itself is not callable):

```js
export const getCounterValue = derived(dataset, $dataset => {
  return value => $dataset.filter(d => d === value).length;
})
```

```html
<script>
  //...
  console.log('2 counter:', $getCounterValue(2)); // $ required for store access
</script>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/911571e064564c69ac0c7455e4a8c769?version=3.48.0)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe a derived store is the correct/necessary approach in your case. You could instead present your data in several formats within a single readable store:

```js
import { readable } from 'svelte/store'

const myArray = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2]

export const myStore = readable({
    raw: myArray,
    sorted: [ ...myArray ].sort(),
    filtered: (val) => myArray.filter(v => v === val),
    counter: (val) => myArray.filter(v => v === val).length,
})
```

and then use your store as follows:

```html
<script>
    import { myStore } from './myStore.js'
    
    console.log('Raw dataset:', $myStore.raw)
    console.log('Sorted dataset:', $myStore.sorted)
    console.log('Filtered dataset (2):', $myStore.filtered(2))
    console.log('Value counter (2):', $myStore.counter(2))
</script>
```

[Demo REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b3371f064dd54928b323c3cc5a07526e?version=3.48.0)

Comment: I would encapsulate it a bit more, so there is only one reference to the source array within the store ([example](https://svelte.dev/repl/c41d98ccf78d465ea5f420398b3f90b6?version=3.48.0)). This way it can updated/set more easily.

Comment: @H.B. not sure I agree with the added complexity, but it certainly is a valid alternative. I also took for granted from the OP that the data was pre-determined, and hence there was no need to be concerned about updates. With a writable store I would indeed proceed slightly differently, and the added complexity of encapsulation would be more justified.

Comment: If the data does not ever change that completely obsoletes the use of stores.

Comment: That's a very bold statement. A readable store could be used to configure an application, for instance. Or to reset a UI state. I can see plenty of uses for stores where data is never updated...

Comment: Why would you use a store if you do not need reactivity? You can just use a regular constant in that case.